# Fast Query Fails After Adding Parameter

Tags: xpath, sitecore, sitecore7

I am using the Sitecore Developer Center Sitecore XPath Builder to create a query.

The following query correctly works in the source field:

`fast:/sitecore/content/#Product Information#/#Image Galleries#//*`

This query returns me all the objects underneath the Image Gallery but this is not what I want.  I want to include only a specific template called "Image Gallery".
I wrote this query.

`fast:/sitecore/content/#Product Information#/#Image Galleries#//*[@@templatename='Image Gallery']`

This query correctly returns the information in the XPath Builder / Sitecore Query Notation but when placed in the Source Field in another item it fails and returns this error.

End of string expected at position 5.

Thanks for reading! :)

Comment: What is the type of your template's field?

Comment: @mdresser It is a droplink.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That should work for all List Type fields. Have you used that exact query as the DataSource of your field? If so you need to prefix with `query:` when specifying as a Source.

`query:fast:/sitecore/content/#Product Information#/#Image Galleries#//*[@@templatename='Image Gallery']`

[Using Sitecore Fast Query](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/developer/using%20sitecore%20fast%20query/using%20sitecore%20fast%20query.pdf)